# Why does sleep interfere with the keyboard suppress hotkey?

Tags: python, python-3.x

example:

```
import keyboard
import time

keyboard.add_hotkey('`', lambda: cpyPstTest() , suppress=True)

def cpyPstTest():
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c')
```

the '`' is supposed to be suppressed, yet it still types out.  Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener loop for keyboard like this.

link for https://nitratine.net/blog/post/how-to-make-hotkeys-in-python/

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: I think that's a different library, and is suppress possible on it?  Not seeing that functionality